# Property "password" does not exists on type Document

Tags: typescript, mongoose, bcrypt

I am getting this error Property "password" does not exists on type Document. So can anyone tell if there is something wrong with my code ?

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});

userSchema.pre("save", function save(next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err: mongoose.Error, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: See [Using mongoose pre-save hook with typescript](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5046#issuecomment-412114160)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add type here with pre-save hook as per the mongoose docs, pre hook is defined as,

```
/**
 * Defines a pre hook for the document.
 */
pre<T extends Document = Document>(
  method: "init" | "validate" | "save" | "remove",
  fn: HookSyncCallback<T>,
  errorCb?: HookErrorCallback
): this;
```

and if you have an interface like below then,

```
export interface IUser {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Add type with pre-save hook,

```
userSchema.pre<IUser>("save", function save(next) { ... }
```

Comment: Also can you please comment the link where this is mentioned . Couldnt find it

Comment: from the mongoose repo, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5046#issuecomment-412114160

Comment: @Barometer Glad, it helped! Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I changed `export interface IUser` to `export interface IUser extends Document {` after `import { Document } from 'mongoose';` which removed the need for defining the `pre<T extends Document = Document>(` above.

Answer (score 7):

I dont know if this will help as the question is old now, however I tried this

```
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose';

const User = mongoose.model<IUser & Document>("users", UserSchema);

type IUser = {
    username: string
    password: string
}
```

`mongoose.model` needs a Document type, and you want to extend that document, therefore Unify the two types

Answer (score 6):

you can also pass the interface type to the schema itself.

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});

interface IUser extends Document{
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the `.pre` function shortly after schema construction, after the interface with the fields defined, is declared.

[image: Image for reference]